# Перестановка элементов в массивах

Tags: массивы, c++builder, c++

в массиве х заменить элементы таким образом, чтобы элементы с четными номерами встали на место нечетных и наоборот, и занести их в массив у-элементы вводятся с клавиатуры..-помогите незнаю как начать

Comment: берем элемент первого массива, если его номер % 2 = 0 заносим его в у на его номер элемента +1 , else его номер элемента -1, учти нумерация с 0 го,  при минимальном знании справиться можно при помощи цикла for, присваиваний и одного оператора if- как это можно записать на с++?

Comment: боюсь ошибиться

Comment: Не-не, смотрите. Когда вы копируете нулевой элемент на место первого, вы же затираете первый элемент. Так что делайте не так: (1) переставьте нулевой и первый элементы; (2) переставьте второй и третий элементы, (4) четвёртый и пятый и т. д.

Так что можно даже без `if` :-)

Comment: вот ниже написала как то но не очень работает, помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем причина-7 ошибок компилятор выдал

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARR_SIZE 10

int main()
{
int arr[10];
int i,c;

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        scanf(" %d",&arr[i]);

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 if(i % 2==0)
 {
 c=arr[i];
 arr[i]=arr[i+1];
 arr[i+1]=c;
 }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)

 printf("%d \n",arr[i]);
}
int arr1[10];
int arr1;

for(i+1<=i;i<10;i++){
 if(i % 2==0)
 {
 arr[i]=arr1[i];
 }
for(i+1<=i;i<10;i++){
 arr[i]=arr1[i];
 }
 }
 getch();
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам вторая часть, начиная от `int arr1[10];`? Она ж вроде вообще не нужна?

Comment: мне же надо с одного массива х перенести элементы в другой массив у, разве не так это делается?все я окончательно уже запуталась...

Comment: А, вы хотите скопировать массив? Ну хорошо. Тогда:

* `int arr1;` там судя по всему по ошибке?
* `for(i+1<=i;` неправильно, надо ж присвоить что-то счётчику
* а что вы хотите сделать первым циклом `for(i+1<=i;i<10;i++)`?

Comment: я там убрала int arr1; у второго массива а то 2 раза ввожу, скомпилировался ввела в массиве х значения в у он выдал не строкой а столбцом элементы и то только 2 поменял элемента....что такое не пойму

Comment: проверка в цикле выполняется чтоб не больше 10 элементов было, а там почему неправильно?

Comment: @Jullietta: ну, вы ж должны присвоить начальное значение счётчику. А то оно у вас останется непонятно каким.

Comment: вообще запуталась теперь

Comment: @Jullietta: смотрите. Вы хотите пробежать индексом `i` от 0 до 9. Это правильно. А что делает код

    `for(i+1<=i;i<10;i++)`

? Для чего проверка `i+1<=i` и где стартовое значение `i`? Вы же раньше сами написали правильно.

PS: У вас должен закончиться лимит комментариев, удаляйте старые.